# Form validation without pushing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textinput, formvalidation.io

I am very new to JQuery and my problem is that I have 3 input fields to enter information about a car (year, make, model) and if the fields are filled out then the year, make and model get pushed into a `garage` array. However, as my code is currently written if the fields are not filled out and the `Add Car` button is clicked, there is an empty string that is pushed to the array. My assignment specifically states to not push an empty array if a user clicks the button when the fields are empty.

```
<body>
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Week 6 Prework Assignment</h1>
  <div id="input">
      <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput"/>
      <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput"/>
      <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput"/>
      <button type="submit" id="addCarButton">Add Car Button</button>
    <ul id='carList'>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
class Car{
  constructor( year, make, model ){
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  } //end constructor
} // end Car class

let garage = [];

function newCar( year, make, model ){
  console.log( 'in newCar:', year, make, model );
  garage.push( new Car( year, make, model ) );
  return true;
}

// on document load
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('#addCarButton').on('click', function newCar(){
    // declare new variable 'addedCar' and set equal to value of year, make and model inputs
    let addedCar = new Car( $( '#yearInput' ).val(), $( '#makeInput' ).val(), $( '#modelInput' ).val() );
    // push 'addedCar' variable to 'garage' array
    garage.push( addedCar );
    // run 'updateCars' function
    updateCars();
    // run 'textRequired' function
    textRequired();
    // empty year, make, model inputs
    $('#yearInput').val( '' );
    $('#makeInput').val( '' );
    $('#modelInput').val( '' );
  });
}); //end ready document

function updateCars(){
  console.log('in updateCars');
  // loop through and display cars on DOM
  let carOutput = $('#carList');
  carOutput.empty();
  for(let car of garage ){
    carOutput.append( '<li>' + car.year + ' ' + car.make + ' ' + car.model + '</li>');
  } // end for of loop
} // end updateCars

function textRequired(){
  if($('#yearInput').val()==='' || $('#makeInput').val()==='' || $('#modelInput').val()===''){
    alert('Please enter text in the required fields');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if statement will check for the value before pushing into the array and if any of the input is empty nothing will happen

```js
class Car{
  constructor( year, make, model ){
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  } //end constructor
} // end Car class

let garage = [];

function newCar( year, make, model ){
  console.log( 'in newCar:', year, make, model );
  garage.push( new Car( year, make, model ) );
  return true;
}

// on document load
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('#addCarButton').on('click', function newCar(){
  if($( '#yearInput' ).val() && $( '#makeInput' ).val() && $( '#modelInput' ).val()){
   let addedCar = new Car( $( '#yearInput' ).val(), $( '#makeInput' ).val(), $( '#modelInput' ).val() );
    // push 'addedCar' variable to 'garage' array
    garage.push( addedCar );
    // run 'updateCars' function
    updateCars();
    // run 'textRequired' function
    textRequired();
    // empty year, make, model inputs
    $('#yearInput').val( '' );
    $('#makeInput').val( '' );
    $('#modelInput').val( '' );
     }
  });
 
    // declare new variable 'addedCar' and set equal to value of year, make and model inputs
   
}); //end ready document

function updateCars(){
  console.log('in updateCars');
  // loop through and display cars on DOM
  let carOutput = $('#carList');
  carOutput.empty();
  for(let car of garage ){
    carOutput.append( '<li>' + car.year + ' ' + car.make + ' ' + car.model + '</li>');
  } // end for of loop
} // end updateCars

function textRequired(){
  if($('#yearInput').val()==='' || $('#makeInput').val()==='' || $('#modelInput').val()===''){
    alert('Please enter text in the required fields');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Week 6 Prework Assignment</h1>
  <div id="input">
      <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput"/>
      <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput"/>
      <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput"/>
      <button type="submit" id="addCarButton">Add Car Button</button>
    <ul id='carList'>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Abdesleem Charif. Thanks! This worked. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the values of year, make and model, and return false if either is empty.

This can be done as follows:

```
$('#addCarButton').on('click', function newCar() {
    if (!$('#yearInput').val() || !$('#makeInput').val() || !$('#modelInput').val()) {
        return false;
    }
    // declare new variable 'addedCar' and set equal to value of year, make and model inputs
    let addedCar = new Car($('#yearInput').val(), $('#makeInput').val(), $('#modelInput').val());
    // push 'addedCar' variable to 'garage' array
    garage.push(addedCar);
    // run 'updateCars' function
    updateCars();
    // run 'textRequired' function
    textRequired();
    // empty year, make, model inputs
    $('#yearInput').val('');
    $('#makeInput').val('');
    $('#modelInput').val('');
});
```

I think doing it this way reads a lot better than encapsulating all your code in an if statement.

Further tips:

1. Consider caching the variables which are being used more than once:

   var $year = $('#yearInput'),
       $make = $('#makeInput'),
       $model = $('#modelInput');

   //Now, use them as: 
   $year.val();
2. Add a common class, say "field" on all the fields and clear them as:

   $(".field").val("");